# Qual a forma certa disso em Curl PHP?

Tags: php, libcurl

Qual a forma correta desse codigo em curl php?

```
curl --user {client_id}:{client_secret} -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d grant_type=client_credentials https://sitealvo.com.br
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

```
// O site alvo:
$ch = curl_init('https://sitealvo.com.br');

// O usuário e senha (o formato é usuario:senha):
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '{client_id}:{client_secret}');

// O cabeçalho:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);

// O corpo (lembrando que ele é um application/x-www-form-urlencoded):
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Faz o curl retornar para váriavel:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Aqui tem o resultado:
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Ou o erro:
$erro = curl_error($ch);
```